# how to achieve an exists filter on ES5.0?

Tags: elasticsearch

The exists filter has been replaced by an exists query in ES5.0.

So how can we achieve, within the same query the equivalent? In other words, we don't want to do two query but just on for various aggregations, including the exists count?

So I want to count the number of time the field "the_field" exists (or is not null)

```
"aggregation":{
   "exists_count":{
      "filter":{
         "exists":{
           "field":"the_field"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use stats aggregation,

```
{ "aggs" : 
       { "time_stats" :               
          { "extended_stats" : 
             { "field" : "time" }
          } 
        } 
}
```

Look at [elastic stats doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-extendedstats-aggregation.html)

Answer (score 0):

With Elastic 5.0, filters didn't so much get replaced by queries, but combined. Syntactically they look the same, but the context in which you use it determines if it gets interpreted as a query (factors into scoring) or as a filter to simply weed out documents. The below code should achieve exactly what you want:

```
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "aggs": {
    "field_exists": {
      "filter": {
        "exists": {
          "field": "name"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The aggregation returned will look something like this, with the doc_count representing the number of documents where the "name field exists. Hope this helps!

```
{
  "aggregations": {
    "field_exists": {
      "doc_count": 11984
    }
  }
}
```